# How to install CUDA 6.5 on Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: nvidia, cuda, 14.10

When trying to install CUDA 6.5 with the .deb file that is provided for 14.04 on Ubuntu 14.10 it states that the package 'cuda' is not found in the repository. The cause of this is probably because there is no official support for 14.10.

I tried to install the new CUDA with the provided .run file with the result that it states that the system is not supported. If I continue anyway, the installation aborts during the driver installation with an unspecified error.

My question would be if there is any other way to try the new CUDA on ubuntu 14.10? Especially as there currently seems to be a problem with the 5.5 version from the official ubuntu repository which prevents my problem from running.

Comment: I do not see this question as off topic at all. I am trying to do exactly the same thing (having successfully run CUDA 6.5 on 14.04 and getting the same error). While I can see that to an expert Ubuntu user this is package management issue, it is still a relevant and likely widespread question that lay users of Ubuntu will want answered in a forum such as this one, even if that answer is "it cannot be done". Moreover, 14.10 is no longer a "development version of Ubuntu".

Comment: Absolutely it would be great even to get a "you can't" answer!

Comment: As a registered CUDA developer, it is now possible to install CUDA 7.0 RC on Ubuntu 14.10 and 15.04. Seems to work.